# Cannot make ssh ForceCommand working

Tags: server, ssh

I am trying to run a command (server-side) every time a user connects, so I set the ForceCommand keyword at the very bottom of the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:

```
ForceCommand /bin/test
```

where:

```
# cat /bin/test
#!/bin/bash

echo "1" >> ~/test.txt

/bin/bash
```

and

```
# ls -l /bin/test
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 47 Mar  8 10:15 /bin/test
```

To make it simple, I am trying to make it working for root user first, but nothing happens (after connecting, the test.txt file is not created in /root)

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much,
Andrea

Using Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS and OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

Comment: How is it related to Ubuntu?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33714333

Comment: @Pilot6 It's about configuration of an OpenSSH server, presumably running on an Ubuntu ststem.

Comment: It doesn't look like an Ubuntu server ;-)

Comment: I am sorry, forgot to mention my system details. I have appended it to the question.

Comment: Why are you expecting `echo "1" >> ~/test.txt` create anything in `/root`? Is the user root?

Comment: @cmak.fr thanks, but I had already checked it and didn't find anything wrong in my configuration...

Comment: @Pilot6 yes it is the root user

Comment: Are you sure? In Ubuntu root user is blocked.

Comment: @Pilot6 root exists on Ubuntu too. Look in /etc/password ! It just has it's password disabled so you can't log in as root.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found the problem. Simply I needed to restart ssh (service ssh restart) after editing the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. Anyway, thanks for your help!